# Send email from today's date

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, outlook

I have an excel spreadsheet for permits, and one column is their expiration dates. My boss wants to be emailed about the permits that expire in the next 2 weeks. How can I use visual basic to tell Outlook to send an email each time he opens the excel spreadsheet?

This is for a spreadsheet I set up, permit names are in column A, dates are in column J.

```
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "Cell A1 is changed" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 4"

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
    .Body = strbody
    'You can add a file like this
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    .Display   'or use .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I may have to use a button to run the program, but I'm not sure if it is possible to schedule emails.

Comment: Take a look at the [Workbook Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.open) event maybe. That should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have not dimmed OutApp as an object.

Once that is done add a loop examining the expiration dates and adding the specific cells to a dynamic array, re-dimming the array with each iteration. Finally each license on the array will need to be added to a text string that can then be added to the body of the email you are creating above....

Once you have all the above working as you would like, you will want to tie the whole operation to the Workbook Open event.

Answer (score 0):

In the VBE, open This Workbook...

Then use the drop-down menus to select the Workbook and Open Event and add your code and save.

[image]